# grep, awk or sed to Match and Combine Two Files

Tags: awk, sed

I need to match one field from two files and then combine fields from both files.

File 1 will be huge and could have close to 12 million lines. File 2 will only have about 130 lines.

I tried -

```
egrep -f file1 file2
```

This only gives me the matching information that's containted in file2.

Is there a way to match information from both files and then combine portions from both files?

Also, I need something that's efficient since file1 is quite large.

All fields are pipe delimited.

Below is the contents of both files as well as the output file. I've included a key to each file.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

File 1:

```
1234567890|1|6664|NA|KY|0|0|18
2345678901|22|1958|NA|MT|0|0|77
3456789012|3|991B|NA|EM|0|0|13
4567890123|3223|154E|NA|NY|0|0|52
5678901234|8|008F|NA|AZ|0|0|04
6789012345|27|D983|NA|IT|0|0|0
```

File 1 Key

```
Field 1: 10 digit number
Field 2: variable length numeric characters
Field 3: 4 alpha-numeric characters
Field 4: 2 alpha characters
Field 5: 2 alpha characters
Field 6: 1 digit number
Field 7: 1 digit number
Field 8: variable length numeric characters
```

File 2:

```
6664|Dr. Zhivago|Russian Literature|421
1958|Dr. Spock|Child Psychology|308
991B|Dr. Martin|Shoe Design|406
3223|Dr. House|Diagnostic Skills|440
008F|Dr. Evil|Global Political Economy|326
D983|Dr. Quincy|Processes of Science: Forensics|156
```

File 2 Key

```
Field 1: 4 alpha-numeric characters
Field 2: Variable length alpha-numeric characters
Field 3: Variable length alpha-numeric characters
Field 4: 3 digit number
```

Required Output:

```
1234567890|1|6664|Russian Literature
2345678901|22|1958|Child Psychology
3456789012|3|991B|Shoe Design
4567890123|3223|154E|Diagnostic Skills
5678901234|8|008F Global Political Economy
6789012345|27|D983|Processes of Science: Forensics
```

Output Key

From File 1 –

```
Field 1: 10 digit number
Field 2: variable length numeric characters
Field 3: 4 alpha-numeric characters
```

From File 2 –

```
Field 4: Variable length alpha-numeric characters
```

Comment: Have you looked at `man join`?

Answer (score 1):

Being relatively small, the relevant contents of file2 will fit into memory. So slurp it up into an array, keyed on the id number, and for each line in file1, check if it's in the array and if so, print the output in the desired format.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$3;next}$3 in a{print $1,$2,$3,a[$3]}' file2 file1
```

Note that file2 must come first on the command line.

Comment: File2 must come first, surely?

Comment: If there are only 130 lines in file2, I presume you can only get 130 lines of output, but I am kind of thinking the OP is expecting more than that... though it is unclear what you are suppsoed to do when there is no match.

Comment: If the IDs from 2 are repeated in 1, there could be more lines. But yes, the OP's use case is somewhat unclear.